# Ajax form submit does not stay on page

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, form-submit

I've got this script that validates my form guestform (from bootstrap) then uses ajax to submit and it works fine and loads on the same page. However, when I added some code that when the radio button "true" is clicked it reveals a hidden part of the form (I was very proud of myself for that) this breaks my ajax submit and it goes to another page and spits out the results from my php file. How can I integrate the on clicks better?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')


  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }
        $("#btnsub").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();


          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $('#guestForm').attr('action'),
            data: $('#guestForm').serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
              $('#output').text(response);
            }
          });

        });
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    });
  //breaks ajax submit
  $('#true').click(function(event) {

    document.getElementById("guests").style.display = "block";
  });
  $('#false').click(function(event) {

    document.getElementById("guests").style.display = "none";
  });
  //breaks ajax submit code

});
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="insert.php" id="guestForm" class="needs-validation" novalidate>

  <div class="col-6">
    <label for="party" class="form-label">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="party" name="party" minlength="4" maxlength="50" aria-describedby=inputGroup-sizing-default " required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback ">Please Enter your full name.</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-label ">Will you be joining us ?"</div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="true" name="att" required />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="true">Joyfully accepts</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="false" name="att" required />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="false">Regretfully declines</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please choose a response.</div>
    </div>



    <div class="col-6" id="guests" name="guests" style="display: none">
      <p>If you are bringing a +1, please enter their name here.</p><br>
      <label for="guest1" class="form-label">Guest Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guest1" name="guest1" placeholder="Optional" minlength="4" maxlength="50">
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please Enter their full name.</div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnsub" name="btnsub">Submit</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: What does the html for `#true` and `#false` elements look like?

Comment: <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="true" name="att" required />
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="true">Joyfully accepts</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="false" name="att" required />
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="false">Regretfully declines</label>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please choose a response.</div>
                </div>

Comment: I see you have an array of forms -- Remember, element `id` values must be unique on the document. And have you stepped through your JavaScript with the debugger and checked your debug console for errors?